# PL/SQL: ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here

Tags: oracle11g

```
Declare

v_U_HFB_STO Varchar(200);
v_RAW_VOL_STO Number ;
v_IO_RAW_VOL_STO Number ;

 

begin

 

select B.U_BACODE||B.U_BANAME into v_U_HFB_STO, SUM(A.RAW_VOL) into v_RAW_VOL_STO, SUM(A.IO_RAW_VOL) into  v_IO_RAW_VOL_STO from UDT_SNAPSHOT_IN_TIME_REPORT A, EXT_S_ITEM B WHERE A.REORDERPOINT<>1 AND A.LOC LIKE 'STO%' AND A.ITEM=B.ITEM GROUP BY (B.U_BACODE||B.U_BANAME);
insert into STAGING.WEEKLY_ANALYSIS_TREND_REPORT_U_HFB_STO values(v_U_HFB_STO,v_RAW_VOL_STO,v_IO_RAW_VOL_STO);

 

end;
/
```

Try to run the code in toad but getting error like [Error] Execution (9: 49): ORA-06550: line 9, column 49:PL/SQL: ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here
ORA-06550: line 9, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Answer (score 1):

Your `select ... into` structure isn't correct; it should have a single `into`:

```
select B.U_BACODE||B.U_BANAME, SUM(A.RAW_VOL), SUM(A.IO_RAW_VOL)
into v_U_HFB_STO, v_RAW_VOL_STO, v_IO_RAW_VOL_STO
from UDT_SNAPSHOT_IN_TIME_REPORT A, EXT_S_ITEM B
WHERE A.REORDERPOINT<>1 AND A.LOC LIKE 'STO%' AND A.ITEM=B.ITEM
GROUP BY (B.U_BACODE||B.U_BANAME);
```

or with modern joins (just because):

```
select B.U_BACODE||B.U_BANAME, SUM(A.RAW_VOL), SUM(A.IO_RAW_VOL)
into v_U_HFB_STO, v_RAW_VOL_STO, v_IO_RAW_VOL_STO
from UDT_SNAPSHOT_IN_TIME_REPORT A
join EXT_S_ITEM B ON A.ITEM=B.ITEM
WHERE A.REORDERPOINT<>1 AND A.LOC LIKE 'STO%'
GROUP BY (B.U_BACODE||B.U_BANAME);
```

Unless you need the variables for something else, you can skip them and do a straight `insert ... select` instead:

```
insert into STAGING.WEEKLY_ANALYSIS_TREND_REPORT_U_HFB_STO
select B.U_BACODE||B.U_BANAME, SUM(A.RAW_VOL), SUM(A.IO_RAW_VOL)
from UDT_SNAPSHOT_IN_TIME_REPORT A
join EXT_S_ITEM B ON A.ITEM=B.ITEM
WHERE A.REORDERPOINT<>1 AND A.LOC LIKE 'STO%'
GROUP BY (B.U_BACODE||B.U_BANAME);
```

Which you can do without PL/SQL too, of course.